# Setting Up S3 with Heroku and Django with Images

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-s3

so I currently have my static files (js and css) just being stored on Heroku which is no biggie. However, I have objects that I need to store multiple images too and be able to get those images on request. How would I store a reference to those images?

I was planning to use a S3 Direct File Upload using these steps on [Heroku here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python#direct-uploading). Is this also going to be the best way for me to do so?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think setting up static (css,js,etc..) or media (images, videos) to be stored on S3 has anything to do with Heroku or where you deploy. Rather, its just making sure Django knows where to save the files, and where to fetch them. I would definitely not follow that link, because it seems confusing and not helpful when working with Django.

This tutorial has really helped me, as it will show you how to set all of that up. I have gone through these steps and can confirm it does the trick. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

Comment: I will take a look at this later today. Does it also provide an example of how to know which database objects store which images?

Comment: I could be understanding you wrong, but I don't think it matters where the images are stored in the databse, because that's just a reference/path to the image. Changing storage to S3 is basically just pointing the `STATIC` and `MEDIA` roots to your S3 bucket instead of wherever they were before.

Comment: With that being said, `python manage.py collectstatic` will throw all your static files into the S3 bucket (the tutorial walks you through this). But, getting your media/image files already in local storage to the new S3 bucket would be the only thing left out of the tutorial. The tutorial is coming from the standpoint of a "new" project.

Comment: Sorry. Let me rephrase. I have items I store in the database from my application. If I want to store images associated to those items would I use a Charfield to store a path to the image on S3, basically removing the need for an ImageField?

Comment: I would still use ImageField because its just easier. Again, you are really just changing the backend here of where the root of these paths look, so you shouldn't have to or want to touch a thing in your database.

Comment: So Django abstracts a layer on how it finds the image from the ImageField by what I defne in my configuration of where to lookm

Answer (score 0):

While I've gone this route in the past, I've recently opted to use Digital Ocean's one-click app - [Dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku). It's based on [Herokuish](https://github.com/gliderlabs/herokuish). I then use Dokku's persistent storage to take advantage of the 25 gigs of storage on DO's smallest, $5/month, plan. I wrote a guide to this [here](https://medium.com/@joshlsullivan/connecting-dokku-persistent-storage-to-django-159d8fc10b8e).